# Can't find a solution for redirecting in IIS7

Tags: iis

We recently switched to Windows Server 2008 x64 running IIS7. Previously we had been using ISAPI_Rewrite by Helicon to use a .htaccess file to redirect.

Unfortunately this no longer works, apparently because of the way the pipeline is setup in .net applications. We need the pipeline in integrated mode, but from what I could find from searches, ISAPI_Rewrite only works in classic mode on IIS7.

So I tried the URL Rewrite Module. But that isn't working either, apparently because it needs the site to run in 64 bit mode only, but we have to have 32 bit mode compatibility due to a Progress database we have running.

Are there any other solutions, or any fixes to get one of these solutions working?

Answer (score 0):

The URLRewrite module works independent of 32-bit and 64-bit application pools so it must be something else that is causing a problem for you. Are you sure your rewrite rule has been properly set up?  A common mistake is to start the **Pattern** under **Match URL** with a slash but you should not include that starting slash.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The rules should be fine as I copied and pasted the rewrite file on our old Windows 2003 server, which was working correctly. I also tried a few simple examples.

Comment: Can you post the part of your web.config that contains the rewrite rule?

Comment: Trying this solution now with URL Rewrite module